# How to use inkwell to popup a menu on press in Flutter

Tags: menu, popup, flutter

I have created a custom widget that contains an Inkwell widget. I would like to popup a selection menu allowing a user to pick an option when the Inkwell is press. Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of problems are there?

Comment: I need to know how to embed a hidden popup menu and only show it when the inkwell is press.

Comment: how is https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showMenu.html

Comment: I need to know how to embed a hidden popup menu and only show it when the inkwell is press. Due to consistency look and feel, I have to create a custom control and add a textbox and dropdown button within an Inkwell. Now I need to show a popup menu when the Inkwell is pressed. Thanks.

Comment: Najeira, I was able to embed the showMenu within my Inkwell and call it on press event. Thanks for suggesting this solution, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Najeira, one more quick question. How do I set the position of the popup menu relative to the Inkwell? Thanks.

Comment: PopupMenuButton uses showMenu internally, this is good example https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart#L872 . Alternatively, it may be better to use the PopupMenuButton directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AlertDialog-class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AlertDialog-class.html) to do that:

```
onPress() {
  showDialog<Null>(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Rewind and remember'),
        content: Text("...")
      );
    },
  );
}
```

***NB! This code does not work. The operation ends with application crash.***

Answer (score -1):

You can use directly the PopupMenuButton it is a widget

```
PopupMenuButton<int>(
      child: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
      itemBuilder: (c) => [
      PopupMenuItem(
      value: 1,
     child: Text('edit'),
      ),
     PopupMenuItem(
     value: 2,
     child: Text('delete'),
  ),
 ],
),
```